# Conditional multiplication of column

Tags: r, if-statement, data-cleaning

I have two columns. One is sales (sales_usd) and the other (sales_unit) indicates whether or not the sales amount is in millions (M) or billions (B):
[the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFQQB.png)

I'm just trying to get everything in billions so if there is an "M" in the units column I want to divide the respective cells in the sales_usd column by 1000.

So far I have

```
data$sales_usd <- if(data$sales_unit="M")
{
  data$sales_usd / 1000
  }
```

but the data remains the same.

Comment: post the data as text and not as image

Comment: Using `transform(data, sales_usd=ifelse(sales_unit == 'M', sales_usd/1000, sales_usd))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`:

```
 df$sales_usd <- ifelse(df$sales_unit == "M", # condition
                        df$sales_usd/1000,    # what if condition is TRUE
                        df$sales_usd          # what if condition is FALSE
                        )
```

Comment: Thanks! this works except I used "M" instead of "B" in the condition

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
library(dplyr)

data |> 
  mutate(sales=ifelse(sales_unit=="M",sales_usd/1000,sales_usd))
```